# Having starting problems of my kia ceed 1.6 crdi model 2010

Tags: starting, cold-start, glowplugs, hot-start

if someone can help me i would be very glad. I appreciate any helpattempt.

The car i am using has difficulties sometimes when starting the engine, independent of the engine temperature sometimes it doesnt start with the first crank attempt. I also had noises from the fuel inejectors which dissapeared after maintaining the fuel injectors but the difficulties when starting especially when the wheather is cold, remained.

I also changed the glowplugs. It seems better now but i think the car should start faster.

Something i noticed is when i turn the ignition key to the on position and keep it there for a long period of time (30 seconds and above) it never starts.

Is this normal?
When the glowplugs heat up in the first couple of seconds when turning key to the on position, do they cool off again after the glowplug sign vanishes from the dashboard??? İs that the reason why my engine wont start after waiting too long. Is that normal?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

My diesel runs the glow plugs for about 10 seconds, and I usually hit the starter at about 7 secs.

They do go off after the light goes out, so cranking the starter after that tends to just flatten the battery. So it is better to re-cycle the glow plugs - a question of understanding the vehicle.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would your car also not start if you would wait too long? What kind of car are you using? But shouldnt the glowplug sign going off be an indicator of "heated up glowplugs" instead of "no more energy is delivered to the glowplugs" since the glowplugs have to be kept warm all the time for the engine to run. If somebody has more information about the glowplug operation during engine start and with running engine i would be very thankful.

Comment: I wrote the operation of the plugs quite clearly.

Comment: glowplugs do not have to be kept warm with running engine. This is why many diesel engines will be able to run (once started) with no battery